# jQuery mousedown not working on file submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit-button

I have a contact form (Drupal Webform) that includes a file upload that creates a form containing this markup (i have stripped the name, size and id attr. in this example):

```
<div class="form-managed-file">
    <input type="file" class="form-file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="form-submit ajax-processed">
    <input type="hidden" value="0">
</div>
```

I would like for the upload button to be clicked automatically on file upload. I have done this in the past with a function like this but it is not working on this one:

```
$('.webform-client-form').on('change', 'input.form-file', function() {
    $(this).next('input[type="submit"]').mousedown();
});
```

However these are working on this form:

```
$('.webform-client-form').on('change', 'input.form-file', function(){
    $(this).next('input[type="submit"]').css("background", "red");
    alert($(this).next('input[type="submit"]').val());
});
```

The first gives the button a red background. The second alerts "Upload". Why is the mousedown not working? I have also used `click()` `trigger("click")` and `trigger("mousedown")` but none of them are clicking the upload button. I am using jQuery 1.10.

Comment: Rather try to submit the form on change?`$('.webform-client-form').on('change', 'input.form-file', function() {
       //submit your form
});`

Comment: As the submit (appears to) only submit the form, you could call `form.submit()` directly.

Comment: The upload field is part of a form that also have multiple text fields, so I do not want to submit the form. I have three different file fields like the one above in the form. So i dont want to submit the form until the user clicks the form submit button. But if a user selects a file and dont click the upload button, the file is not submitted when the form is submitted. That is why i want it to automatically upload when a file is selected..

Answer (score 0):

You're only triggering mousedown. You also need to capture the trigger and act accordingly, such as:

```
$('.webform-client-form').on('mousedown', 'input[type="submit"]', function() {
    alert ("mousedown");
});
```

If I am not wrong, what you're trying to do is to submit the form when the `.change` is triggered. If that's the case, you might as well submit the form within your `.change` handler, such as:

```
$('.webform-client-form').on('change', 'input.form-file', function() {
    $('.webform-client-form').submit();
});
```

Comment: But i do not want to submit the form, i only want to simulate a click on the upload button, to make sure that the file gets uploaded.

Comment: But i dont understand how that would help me. I want to simulate a click on the button and nothing else. I dont want to run any functions on the click i just to simulate a click on the button. Normally i would do this by using $(element).click() or  $(element).mousedown().

Comment: Maybe this illustrates it better: http://jsfiddle.net/xLuv2dq9/ .
After one second there is triggered a click on the blue div. And after the input is changed there is triggered a click on the blue div. Both resulting in an alert. But why does it not simulate a click on the upload button to upload the file?

Comment: Is this what you're after => [http://jsfiddle.net/xLuv2dq9/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/xLuv2dq9/1/) or the old/not-recommended way => [http://jsfiddle.net/xLuv2dq9/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/xLuv2dq9/2/)

Comment: No but this is it: http://jsfiddle.net/9b6c7w5g/ . The "upload startet" alert is triggered on upload because it simulates a click on the button. But i have tried this in my code and it does not start the upload of my file.... It's a bit strange, because if i just click the button the upload will start..

Comment: It _could be_ a timing issue. Try with a time out like [http://jsfiddle.net/9b6c7w5g/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/9b6c7w5g/1/) and see if that works.

Comment: I already tried the timeout.. then it return undefined when alerting the value of the input submit button..?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `click()` works fine:

```
 $(this).next('input[type="submit"]').css("background", "red").click();
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nghkbzwx/3/).

Comment: But if you place an alert inside the click in a function it does not fire.. So the css() works, but it does not click:
$(this).next('input[type="submit"]').css("background", "red").click(function(){
     alert("test");
    });

Comment: Because in such a way you are binding and action to `onClick` event, not triggering it. Here is updated fiddle where at first an `alert()` is binded to `onClick` event, and the click is triggered: http://jsfiddle.net/nghkbzwx/5/

Comment: Or you can simply add  `.click()` to your statement: 
`$(this).next('input[type="submit"]').css("background", "red").click(function(){ alert("test"); }).click();` But in this case binding is performed on every input change.

Comment: Maybe this illustrates it better: http://jsfiddle.net/xLuv2dq9/ .
After one second there is triggered a click on the blue div. And after the input is changed there is triggered a click on the blue div. Both resulting in an alert. But why does it not simulate a click on the upload button to upload the file?

Comment: What do you mean by "upload the file"? Send it to the server?

Comment: Yes.. If i select a file and click the upload button manually the file is uploaded, the input field changes to a link to the file, and the upload button changes to a remove button. So the file is now uploaded to the server. All that happens when i click the upload button so i do not understand why it does not work to simulate a click when the file input changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90430/discussion-between-lazarev-alexandr-and-user2969934).